# Selecting Specific Rows with Date and Time values in Rstudio

Tags: r

In order to investigate the seasonality effect in my data set, I want to select rows with a specific date and time values. I have multiple rows with the same date and time value ( i have combined multiple CSV files, each starting from the first day of January to the last day of December). I am using the following code;

> filter(data,data$DateTime > "2019-01-01" & data$DateTime < "2019-03-01" )

but the results are not what I want. How can I select my desired range of date and time and save it in a distinct data frame to perform my analysis on it?

Thank you

Comment: could you provide `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: structure(c("function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, ", 
"    verbose = getOption(\"verbose\"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) ", 
"{", "    fileExt <- function(x) {", "        db <- grepl(\"\\\\.[^.]+\\\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$\", x)", 
"        ans <- sub(\".*\\\\.\", \"\", x)"), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

Comment: what is the result of `class(data)`, it looks more like a function than a dataframe.

Comment: if this is a function, make sure to call it with `data()`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(datatable)

dt <- setDT(your_df)

dt_sub <- dt[DateTime > "2019-01-01" & DateTime < "2019-03-01", ]
```

I think this should work, let me know if it helped.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help

Comment: If this does resolve your question, once you're certain of it please come back and accept the answer. (It's courtesy/etiquette on SO that many new users don't initially recognize.)